# tableView with interface builder-Cells are empty

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I made w tableView Controller with interface builder , i made few cell's  set it to basic and define some text into each cell, but when i start my app, cell's are empty?

Comment: You need to post a lot more information. iOS? OSX ? You might want screenshots too

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your table view's delegate and data source.

In the data source methods you can specify the number of cells, etc.

Read [Apple's Table View Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).